# Tensorboard: Scalar graph x-axis is wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using Tensorboard (with Tensorflow 1.3, Python 3.6, Windows 10 64bit) to visualise training progress of a simple MLP. Every second or third time I open tensorboard to visualise some results, the scalar graphs are jumbled. It's like the x-axis of the graph points gets muddled somewhere. Does anyone know what causes this issue / how to fix it?

[image: Tensorboard: muddled graph]

Comment: You keep writing to the same directory so there are multiple data points at each time step. You should use a separate log directory for each run or empty the old one before logging again.